# decodeURI doesn't replace encoding

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue decoding a string.

```js
var myText = "test [u0027] test";
myText = myText.replace("\[u","\\u");
myText = myText.replace("]","")

console.log(decodeURI(myText));
```

It does not replace the by a character. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: `decodeURI` - as the name suggests - decodes [URI encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding), also known as "percent-encoding". For example, `decodeURI("test %27 test")` will return `"test ' test"`.  What exactly do you want to do? Where does the input string come from? (If it's not from an URI you are using the wrong function.) What is the bigger picture?

Comment: @RoToRa - The original string comes from another system. When the source string contains "test \u0027 test", the string is decoded perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `\u0027` is resolved by the Javascript-code interpreter, which converts it into a "real" string.

That means you can not build the `\u0027` dynamically, because `"\u"` is not even a valid string.

`"\\u"` is a valid string, which gets resolved to the *actual* string `"\u"`, but that is not the "magic" unicode marker, it's just what you see.

You can imagine it like:

```
console.log("\u0027");
```

gets converted to:

```
console.log("'");
```

before the javascript code (the `console.log`) is actually executed.

The `%27` syntax *can* be dynamically built, because it already is a real string:

```
decodeURI( '%' + '27' )
```

*Also Note:*

Maybe the `String.fromCodePoint` function is useful to you:

```
String.fromCodePoint( 0x27 )
```